# Haxe interface compile to swc with native getter/setter

Tags: flash, interface, haxe

How to compile swc from haxe source interface with support native getter/setter. When i use:

```
interface ITest<T>
{
#if flash
    @:getter(x) function gx():Int;
    @:setter(x) function sx(_v:Int):Int;
#else
#end
    var x(get_x, set_x):Int;
}
```

I get swc with:

```
public interface ITest
{
    function get gx () : int;
    function set sx (_v:int) : void;
    function add (_v:Object) : void;
}
```